# Google cloud speech API streaming: RequestObserver.onCompleted() still causes "OUT_OF_RANGE: Exceeded maximum allowed stream duration" error

Tags: google-cloud-speech

Using the Google cloud speech API's streaming requires the length of a streaming session to be less than 60 seconds. To handle streaming beyond this limitation, we would require to split the streaming data in to several chunks, using something like single_utterance, for example. When submitting such chunk, we use the "RequestObserver.onCompleted()" to mark the end of streaming session. However it seems like the Grpc threads which were created to handle streaming running even after getting the final results, causing the error "io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: OUT_OF_RANGE: Exceeded maximum allowed stream duration of 65 seconds".

1. Is there any other mechanisms that could be used to properly terminate Grpc threads, so that it won't run until the allowed 60 second limit? (Seems like we could use SpeechClient.close() or SpeechClient.shutdown() to release all background resources, but would require recreating the SpeechClient instances again. This would be somewhat heavy.)
2. Is there any other recommended ways that we could use to stream data beyond the 60 second limit, without splitting the stream to several chunks.

Parameters : [Encoding=LINEAR16,Rate=44100]

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46817675/6121516) help you?